# How to remove duplicates in each row

Tags: python, dataframe, list, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with duplicates in each row. I would like to return the non duplicates with a new column name like Num1 thru Num5.
For instance,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
 
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,2,4,5,6,7,7],
           [2,5,6,7,22,23,34,7],
           [3,3,5,6,7,45,46,7],
           [4,6,7,14,29,32,33,7],
           [5,6,7,13,23,33,35,7],
           [6,1,6,7,8,9,10,7],
           [7,0,2,5,7,10,30,7]], 
           columns = ['Row_Num', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6','Num7'])
```

I would like my results to be like this.

```
result = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,2,4,5,6],
           [2,5,6,22,23,34],
           [3,3,5,6,45,46],
           [4,6,14,29,32,33],
           [5,6,13,23,33,35],
           [6,1,6,8,9,10],
           [7,0,2,5,10,30]], 
           columns = ['Row_Num', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5'])
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  For example, your 3rd row has duplicated 3s and duplicated 7s.  How are we to know which ones to remove?

Comment: 3 is the row number. 7 is the duplicate

Comment: All pandas rows have to have the same number of elements.  Are you GUARANTEED there will always be a pair of duplicates in EVERY row?  In your example, the rows are in sorted order, except for the dups.  Is that also guaranteed?

Comment: Sorry updated my question

Comment: Is the duplicate value we are looking for in each row the value in the column named `Num7`? If so, could the values ​​in column `Num7` be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid transposing the dataframe you can use `iterrows` instead of `items` as in my other answer, and using `drop_duplicates`  as @Timeless proposed this is a bit faster than the other answers currently:

```
remaining_values = {row_num: values.drop_duplicates(keep=False).values
                    for row_num, values in df1.set_index('Row_Num').iterrows()}
result = pd.DataFrame(remaining_values).T.rename(columns=lambda i: f"Num{i+1}")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
   Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5
1     1     2     4     5     6
2     5     6    22    23    34
3     3     5     6    45    46
4     6    14    29    32    33
5     6    13    23    33    35
6     1     6     8     9    10
7     0     2     5    10    30
```

The last step will only work if there are an equal number of duplicated values in each row, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible option :

```
tmp = df1.set_index("Row_Num").T

out = (tmp.apply(lambda s: (t:=s.drop_duplicates(keep=False))
            .set_axis(tmp.index[:len(t)])).T.reset_index())
```

Output :

```
print(out.convert_dtypes())

   Row_Num  Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5
0        1     1     2     4     5     6
1        2     5     6    22    23    34
2        3     3     5     6    45    46
3        4     6    14    29    32    33
4        5     6    13    23    33    35
5        6     1     6     8     9    10
6        7     0     2     5    10    30

[7 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Don't often see the Walrus operator in use. Nice!

Comment: Can you apply over rows instead, to avoid the transposing steps?

Comment: Actually, there is nothing bad with doing a double transpose. It is done under the under in many functions of the API ;)

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation is that you want to remove all values that are duplicated in each row.

```
values_transposed = df1.set_index('Row_Num').T
duplicates_by_row = {row_num: values.duplicated(keep=False) 
                     for row_num, values in values_transposed.items()}
remaining_values = {row_num: values_transposed.loc[~dups, row_num].values 
                    for row_num, dups in duplicates_by_row.items()}
result = pd.DataFrame(remaining_values).T.rename(columns=lambda i: f"Num{i+1}")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
   Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5
1     1     2     4     5     6
2     5     6    22    23    34
3     3     5     6    45    46
4     6    14    29    32    33
5     6    13    23    33    35
6     1     6     8     9    10
7     0     2     5    10    30
```

The last step will only work if there are an equal number of duplicated values in each row, as others have pointed out.

Comment: Output gave me this :

Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5  Num6  Num7
0     1     5     3     6     6     1     0
1     2     6     5    14    13     6     2
2     4    22     6    29    23     8     5
3     5    23    45    32    33     9    10
4     6    34    46    33    35    10    30

Comment: Sorry, updated the code to match the output.  I left the `Row_Num` values as the index but if you want to move them to a column as in your desired output just do `result.reset_index(names='Row_Num')`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If duplicate value column is `Num7` and the values ​​in column `Num7` always same you can use:

```
df1[df1.columns[1:-1]] = df1[df1.columns[1:-1]].replace(df1["Num7"].iloc[0],np.nan)

values = [df1.iloc[i][:-1].dropna().tolist() for i in range(len(df1))]

out = pd.DataFrame(values ,columns = ['Row_Num', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5'])
```

**Out**:

```
   Row_Num  Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5
0      1.0   1.0   2.0   4.0   5.0   6.0
1      2.0   5.0   6.0  22.0  23.0  34.0
2      3.0   3.0   5.0   6.0  45.0  46.0
3      4.0   6.0  14.0  29.0  32.0  33.0
4      5.0   6.0  13.0  23.0  33.0  35.0
5      6.0   1.0   6.0   8.0   9.0  10.0
6      7.0   0.0   2.0   5.0  10.0  30.0
```